# Trying to get SQL query to return sum of a column where customerId is equal to give customerId

Tags: java, sql

I have sql query which is supposed to go to booking a get the sum of the amount paid column and some of cost column when given a customer id.
However when I execute it returns on 100 for total_cost sum and 100 for amount_paid sum  however the sum for total cost should be 1000

```
SELECT SUM(cost) AS 'total_cost', SUM(amount_paid) AS 'amount_paid' FROM booking WHERE ID = 'customerId'
```

when executing `resultSet.getString("total_cost");` it returns 100 same for `amount_paid`, I have also tried doing `resultSet.getString(2);` same problem.
What am I doing wrong?

Columns in booking table: 
ID, cost, amount_paid, customer_id

Rows inserted into booking table

```
1 100 100,
2 300 100,
3 500 100,
4 100 100,
5 0 100,
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Delete "WHERE id = 'customerId'". :)

Comment: just understood what went wrong i was calling by ID instead of customer_id thankyou!

Answer (score 0):

> I have sql query which is supposed to go to booking a get the sum of the amount paid column and some of cost column when given a customer id. However when I execute it returns on 100 for total_cost sum and 100 for amount_paid sum however the sum for total cost should be 1000

So the expected answer would be total_cost = 1000 (where all values are added) and amount_paid = 100 (or whatever the relating value is for that customer)?

Your issue then would be that since the total_cost and amount_paid are being placed together in the query, it is limiting the total_cost based on the customer ID as well.  I would suggest splitting it into two queries.  Or if the single query needs to be maintained you could use a subquery to retrieve the total_cost without being limited by the customer ID.

```
SELECT 
   (SELECT SUM(cost) FROM booking) AS 'total_cost', 
   SUM(amount_paid) AS 'amount_paid' 
FROM booking 
WHERE ID = 'customerId'
```